# helm-mini sort buffer names as helm-recenf

Tags: helm, helm-sources, helm-for-files

`helm-recentf` and `helm-mini` functions sort buffers or files based on the time at which I opened the file or buffer.

Problem happens after typing character in helm buffer.

While `helm-recentf` function works as intended, the search algorithm in `helm-mini` behaves slightly differently and it sorts items with most matching character and order changes every time when I press keyboard.

I would like all `helm-mini` items will be sorted in the same way as `helm-recentf`, based on the time they were opened (either as a buffer or file).

**PS**:

I set all **fuzzy-search** variables to nil still behavior is the same

```
(setq helm-mode-fuzzy-match nil)
(setq helm-ff-fuzzy-matching nil)
(setq helm-M-x-fuzzy-match nil)
(setq helm-locate-fuzzy-match nil)
(setq helm-use-fuzzy nil)
```